# TT Earthing System

Tags: grounding

Ok guys I can't just understand a thing of the TT Earthing System, why on it the ground of the power cabin is connected to the neutral of the power cabin?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power distribution to the customer via L1, L2, L3 (in the case of three phase) is sufficient to power 3-phase loads.  The neutral wire is grounded at the source and is extended to the customer as a ground reference.  Under normal load conditions, there should be no current flowing on the neutral wire.  However, a single phase voltage can be picked up between one of the line (L1..3) and neutral, in which case current would be present on the neutral wire.

Equipment at the customer premises must be grounded for safety.  Grounding it solely through the neutral will work as long as there is no fault in the wire back to the distribution point or drop.  Because a fault can exist on the neutral from a downed wire or corroded connection, the neutral is tied to the protective ground at the customer breaker box.  Inside the breaker box, Ground and Neutral are connected together.  A ground rod driven into the ground near the service entrance establishes the ground for the.

So, while single phase current return is via the neutral wire, an additional protective ground exists at the customer site to protect against wiring and equipment faults that could cause fire or shock hazard.

Comment: What you've described is the TN system (TN-C-S to be precise), but OP asks about TT system where neutral line is NOT connected to LOCAL ONLY protective earth.

Comment: @JakubRakus you are correct, but although he asked about TT, what he described sounded like TN-C-S when he stated that N was grounded at the cabin.  I suppose another way to interpret his dilemma is he had a spec that called for TT but a contractor or supplier connected incorrectly per TN-C-S.

Comment: I took 'cabin' to be a poor translation of distribution box or similar and being the terminals on the left. OP seems happy with this answer though so I'm not sure what his real question was.

Comment: @Transistor  I interpreted cabin as a portable or temporary control room.  Without sufficient detail we each infer different meanings influenced by our individual points of reference.

Answer (score 0):

**neutral** ˈnjuːtr(ə)l
adjective

1. not supporting or helping either side in a conflict, disagreement, etc.; impartial.
   "neutral and non-aligned European nations"
2. having no strongly marked or positive characteristics or features.
   "her tone was neutral, devoid of sentiment"

In electrical systems neutral is neither positive or negative with respect to Earth. It has (ideally) no voltage. To make a line neutral one point of (an otherwise floating) supply is connected to ground/earth usually through metal rods or plates buried in the ground.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of an earth system (of whatever type) is to do two things:

- Reduce touch voltages, so that a human making contact with accidentally live metal does not die.
- Provide for sufficient current to flow back to the source of supply to open the protective devices in a reasonable time (Because the first thing is in general not always practical).

The first objective can be largely achieved by bonding all the exposed metalwork together, at least in doors. This ensures that touching say a metal tap at the same time as a faulty washing machine will not cause overly large potential across the body, but this leaves inevitable edge cases that are still dangerous, so it is desirable to still disconnect in a reasonable time.

To provide the return current path required for the second case, it is necessary to provide a means for fault current to return to the transformer (Current flows in loops, always). There are various ways to do this, ranging from TN-S where a complete separate conductor is used back to the star point, TN-C-S where a combined earthed neutral is used, IT, and TT where the body of earth is used as the conductor, in all cases however the objective is to provide a return path so fault current (IT is often a bit of a special case) flows to the star point via a highly reliable route so as to reliably blow fuses or (these days) trip earth leakage detectors.

The star point ground also serves to define the common mode voltage of the network as being close to that of the local body of earth, so that it does not static charge up and end up blowing out the insulation somewhere inconvenient (Underground or inside a MVA class transformer counts as an inconvenient insulation failure).

Note that 'EARTH' is not fundamentally anything special, if is just a convenient reasonably conductive, cheap way to ensure that a fault causes sufficient current to flow to open a breaker (In fact on a TT install the impedance is often high enough that an RCD is about the ONLY thing it will open).

IT is a bit of a special, usually only seen in medium or high voltage work where limiting fault current is desirable to avoid plant damage or in special locations where being able to detect a 'first fault' without that necessarily forcing an immediate shutdown is desirable (Hospital operating rooms, steel mills, semiconductor plants).